# Is it possible to subtract the values of 2 subqueries and return the difference?

Tags: mysql, subquery

The logic behind this is that I want to subtract the returned products from the sold products. That way I will have a net quantity of products sold. The subqueries return numeric values but I'm not sure how to get the difference from these subqueries.

```
SELECT COUNT(QUANTITY_ORDERED) FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(QUANTITY_ORDERED) FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CATEGORY ='SOLD')-(SELECT COUNT(QUANTITY_ORDERED) FROM PRODUCTS WHERE CATEGORY='RETURNED')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a conditional `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`

```
SELECT product_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY ='SOLD' THEN QUANTITY_ORDERED ELSE 0 END)
     - SUM(CASE WHEN CATEGORY ='RETURNED' THEN QUANTITY_ORDERED ELSE 0 END) as total
FROM products
GROUP BY product_id
```

OR

```
SELECT product_id, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN CATEGORY ='SOLD' THEN 0 END)
     - COUNT(CASE WHEN CATEGORY ='RETURNED' THEN 0 END) as total
FROM products
GROUP BY product_id
```

Comment: Show me sample data and expected result to be sure what you want. But shuld be easy to change.

Comment: Good, you confused me when used `QUANTITY_ORDERED` .